# Crear una tabla con el campo hora con el formato HH:MM donde HH IN [00, 23] y MM IN [00, 59]

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy comenzando en Oracle usando Oracle SQL developer y tengo una duda:

¿Cómo creo una tabla con el campo hora con el formato `HH:MM` donde `HH IN [00, 23]` y `MM IN [00, 59]`? ¿Y el `check` de esto cómo sería?

Pues debería de realizar un `CHECK` para saber que los valores que el usuario introduce en `HH` están entre 00 y 23 y en `MM` entre 00 y 59.

Por ahora llevo esto pero no creo que este bien:

```
CREATE TABLA CONSULTA
(H_INI TO_CHAR(DATETIME(4), 'HH:MM') CHECK(HH BETWEEN 00 AND 23)AND CHECK(MM BETWEEN 00 AND 59) NOT NULL,
H_FIN TO_CHAR(DATETIME(4), 'HH:MM') CHECK(HH BETWEEN 00 AND 23) AND CHECK(MM BETWEEN 00 AND 59)NOT NULL);
```

Para realizar este ejercicio tengo que usar las conversiones entre tipo de datos.

Comment: Hola usuario nuevo, las preguntas deben incluir al menos un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) o lo que esté usted intentando, agregue más información a la pregunta para poder ayudarle. Recomiendo que lea [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y la demás documentación sobre el funcionamiento de este sitio.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarnos qué motor de bases de datos estás usando? ¿A qué te refieres con "el check de esto cómo sería"?

Answer (score 2):

Si estás usando SQL Server, existe un tipo "time":
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Lo usarías así:

```
CREATE TABLE MiTabla (
  hora time(0)
)

insert into Mitabla values ('10:02')
```

Comment: Antes de redactar una respuesta asumiendo algo, deberías preguntarlo en un comentario.

Comment: Lo hago así porque en el Stackoverflow en inglés hay montones de preguntas donde se proponen diferentes soluciones para diferentes SGBD y resultan de bastante utilidad. Es verdad que no vengo al StackOverflow en español muy a menudo, pero si la práctica habitual aquí es así, de ahora en adelante lo haré como me indicas.

Comment: Todos agradecemos tu ayuda, pero en este caso en particular tu sugerencia funciona en prácticamente todos los SGDB (con pequeñas modificaciones), pero no hace lo que pide el OP. Si haces un `SELECT * FROM Mitabla` verás que te ha guardado un registro con la hora `10:02:00`, y eso no es lo que desea.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Pues hace un SUBSTR(hora, 1, 5) y fuera. Ah, que eso también hay que explicarlo. No veas. La recomendación de usar un campo de tipo time me parece acertada y bien asumido. A mí también me está costando adaptarme a es.SO ;)

Comment: A ver @JoséCarlosPHP, aún no tenemos claro los requerimientos porque estamos preguntando a base de comentarios y aún no nos lo ha dejado claro. Este tipo de situaciones (campos que requieren de un formato en particular o contenido que debe ser comprobado antes de permitir insertarlo en la base de datos) se suelen solventar con iniciadores (triggers), pero la forma de crear uno varía considerablemente de un SGBD a otro. PD: Yo veo buena esa observación y válida para una respuesta o como sugerencia de alternativa a lo que está pidiendo.

Comment: Entendido y +1 ¡Gracias!

Comment: @OscarGarcia en mi opinión el tipo de datos correcto para guardar la hora es "time" y si luego lo que quiere es mostrarlo en otro formato, lo tendrá que manejar en la capa de presentación. Meter un trigger para formatear un dato, también en mi opinión, no es la solución. En cualquier caso, pido disculpas y de ahora en adelante preguntaré antes para adaptarme al SGBD (aunque sigo pensando que sería útil tener respuestas para diferentes SGBD en la misma pregunta).

Comment: @CarlosAdrián , tras la última edición se ve claramente que está usando Oracle como SGBD y Oracle, precisamente, no tiene campo de solo hora (hora, minutos y segundos).

Answer (score 2):

La función `CHECK` requiere una única expresión que al evaluarse resulte cierta o falsa, por lo que no puedes concatenar varios `CHECK`.

Para crear la restricción solo en uno de los campos (por poner un ejemplo) deberías hacer:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla (
  H_INI VARCHAR(5)

  CONSTRAINT H_INI CHECK(
    SUBSTR(H_INI, 1, 2) BETWEEN 00 AND 23
    AND SUBSTR(H_INI, 4, 2) BETWEEN 00 AND 59
    AND SUBSTR(H_INI, 3, 1) = ':'
  )
)
```

De esta manera estamos comprobando que:

- Los primeros dos caracteres están comprendidos entre 0 y 23.
- Los últimos dos caracteres están comprendidos entre 0 y 59.
- El tercer carácter es el separador `:`.

Puedes comprobar el correcto funcionamiento (usando Oracle 11g) en el siguiente enlace:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=375d1fd80e482f3f0f7e2e1123db77a1

---

Edición para agregar la nueva restricción (`H_INI <= H_FIN`):

```
-- Esquema de la tabla
CREATE TABLE tabla (
  H_INI VARCHAR(5),
  H_FIN VARCHAR(5)
)
-- Restricciones en H_INI
ALTER TABLE tabla ADD
  CONSTRAINT H_INI CHECK(
    SUBSTR(H_INI, 1, 2) BETWEEN 00 AND 23
    AND SUBSTR(H_INI, 4, 2) BETWEEN 00 AND 59
    AND SUBSTR(H_INI, 3, 1) = ':'
  )
-- Restricciones en H_FIN
ALTER TABLE tabla ADD
  CONSTRAINT H_FIN CHECK(
    SUBSTR(H_FIN, 1, 2) BETWEEN 00 AND 23
    AND SUBSTR(H_FIN, 4, 2) BETWEEN 00 AND 59
    AND SUBSTR(H_FIN, 3, 1) = ':'
  )
-- Restricciones entre H_INI y H_FIN
ALTER TABLE tabla ADD
  CONSTRAINT H_INI_FIN CHECK(H_INI <= H_FIN)
```

Puedes ver el correcto funcionamiento en el siguiente enlace:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e3a0ece57819db52b97533e3da7cc01a

Answer (score 0):

al no tener sufucientes puntos no puedo responder al comentario así que lo escribo por aquí, en el ejemplo que me has enviado a la hora de meter los valores con INSERT VALUES, el valor que tendrá que meter el usuario será: 00:30 o solo 0030.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Debe introducir `00:30`. En el enlace se ven los ejemplos. Pulsa en el botón "run" para ver el funcionamiento.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias. Ya lo he comprobado.

Comment: Una pregunta, también tengo que añadir la siguiente restricción: h_ini <= h_fin, esto se podría escribir como ```CONSTRAINT EN_HORA CHECK(H_INI<=H_FIN)```` ?? Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, espero que haya sido de ayuda. Si mi respuesta ha solucionado tu problema recuerda marcarla como correcta pulsando en el botón **✓** que hay inmediatamente a la izquierda de mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Edito mi respuesta para que incluya esa última restricción. PD: quizá tarde, está la comida en la mesa.

Comment: No te preocupes, no tengo prisa. Muchas gracias de verdad.

Comment: No se puede crear una comprobación en la que intervengan dos campos diferentes. Da un error *Column check constraint cannot reference other columns*. De modo que la solución podría pasar por un iniciador (trigger) que realice la comprobación.

Comment: La seccion de repuestas, son para bueno, las repuestas, si tienes algo que agregar siempre puedes editar tu pregunta, al aceptar repuestas puedes ganar tus primero puntitos para despues acceder a los comentarios

Comment: @Ana , he editado mi respuesta agregando la nueva restricción funcionando. No sé por qué me daba el error cuando lo metía todo dentro del `CREATE TABLE`, por lo que lo he sacado fuera mediante `ALTER TABLE` para ir depurando y me ha dejado a la primera. Deduzco que en el intento anterior se me coló algo mal x)